# How to do pattern matching on a binary in Erlang?

Tags: binary, erlang, pattern-matching

I would like to do recursion over a binary, and in each call read up to 32 bits from the binary, and return it in a new binary. But I can't get the pattern matching to work as I want.

```
binaryToBinary(Source) ->
    binaryToBinaryAux(Source, <<>>).

binaryToBinaryAux(<<>>, Target) ->
    Target;
binaryToBinaryAux(<<H:32/binary, T/binary>>, Target) ->
    binaryToBinaryAux(<<T/binary>>, <<Target/binary, H>>).
```

Here is the error I get for the pattern matching:

```
10> mymodule:binaryToBinary(<<"JonasPonas">>).
** exception error: no function clause matching
                    mymodule:binaryToBinaryAux(<<"JonasPonas">>,<<>>) 
                                                          (mymodule.erl, line 51)
```

What am I doing wrong with the pattern matching of the binary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pattern `<<H:32/binary, T/binary>>` matches a binary containing at least 32 bytes, assigning the first 32 bytes to H and the remaining bytes to T. The pattern `<<>>` matches the empty binary. These are your only patterns.

`<<"JonasPonas">>` is neither empty nor does it have at least 32 bytes. Therefore it does not match either of your patterns and you get the error you do.

To fix this add a pattern that handles binaries that have less than 32 bytes (you can also get rid of the empty pattern as it will then be redundant).

Comment: I added a case with `binaryToBinaryAux(<<Bin/binary>>, Target) -> Target.` but then I get this error: `** exception error: bad argument in function  mymodule:binaryToBinaryAux/2`

Comment: @Jonas But not on the input `<<"JonasPonas">>`, right? I get that error when I run your code on input with more than 32 bytes (even without the additional case). To fix it replace `H` with `H/binary` on the 7th line of the code you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work correctry:

```
binaryToBinary(Source) ->
    binaryToBinaryAux(Source, <<>>).

binaryToBinaryAux(<<>>, Target) ->
    Target;
binaryToBinaryAux(<<H:32/binary, T/binary>>, Target) ->
    binaryToBinaryAux(<<T/binary>>, <<Target/binary, H/binary>>);
binaryToBinaryAux(Rest, Target) ->
    binaryToBinaryAux(<<>>, <<Target/binary, Rest/binary>>).
```